# Is my surge and burst protection enough?

Tags: emc, burst

[image]

The above schematic is for surge and burst proection. Is it enough? Thanks.

Comment: Only practical testing will tell.

Comment: What standard do you want to comply with? If you look at a PC power supply, you’ll find they will use varistors, not TVS diodes.

Comment: @Kartman And there are varistors in this schematic, so...?

Comment: Yes, varistors in series with a GDT. Not something I’ve observed before. Usually the GDT is the front line defence as it has a fair amount of ‘let through’ but a very low impedance once triggered. Then followed by varistors to clean up the rest.